# How to know user has removed ios widget?

Tags: ios, widget

When user has set a Widget, developer can know user has set it by widget appear event.
Now I want to know whether user has remove it.
When user has removed it, I won't write data to userdefault for widget use.
So how to know user has removed the widget?
Does iOS raise an event when user remove the widget?

Comment: Add more details on what exactly you want to achieve..it's unclear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS8 Today Extension: Detect removed or added today extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26622393/ios8-today-extension-detect-removed-or-added-today-extension)